# Content gets pushed down and I don't understand now

Tags: html, css

I want my layout to look like this:

[image: click]

but it looks like this:

[image: click]

(I'm talking about the text on the right side of the image).

Why does it happen and how can I make it look the same?

This is for a project, and I can't use any reset/normalize file (in case of the browser throwing off the design).

I don't know how to also add the image in the snippet, I would've done that so you get a better representation of my problem.

Thanks.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #457c05;
    background-image: url('./img/img03.jpg');
}

.container {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.titlu-website {
    color: #1A1A1A;
    font-size: 64px;
}

.meniu-navigatie {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button-link {
    padding: 0 30px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Nova Mono', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #B5B5B5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.active {
    padding-left: -10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.titlu {
    color: #1A1A1A;
}

.continut-langa-imagine {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #808080;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 180%;
    width: 400px;
}

.imagine-centrala {
    border: 6px solid #EEE7DF;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="titlu-website">
            Black/White
        </div>
        <ul class="meniu-navigatie">
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link active">Home</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Photos</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Links</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="continut">
        <div class="rand">
            <h3 class="titlu">Welcome to Black/White</h3>
            <img src="./img/img02.jpg" class="imagine-centrala">
            <div class="continut-langa-imagine">
                Sed lacus. Donec lectus. Nullam pretium nibh ut turpis. Nam bibendum. In nulla tortor, elementum ipsum. Proin imperdiet est. Phasellus dapibus semper urna. Pellentesque ornare, orci in felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus egestas at sem.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its because of: `.continut-langa-imagine { display: inline-block; }`. That line will swap the textblock to an inline element and it will start at the end line of the image. What you actually should use is either `flexbox`, `css-grid` or `float`. Using `inline-block` is a compeltely wrong approach.

Comment: then how can I position it properly? (without using float)

Comment: @tacoshy can you look on my snippet? I want all the divs to look like that one in the photo and I don't know how to do it with float (I can't use flexbox and css-grid because I didn't study them)

Comment: So you're not allowed to use float, css-grid or flexbox? this pretty much cuts it down to use a table out of its actual use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have studied your CSS and it's not immediately clear to me *why* you should need to do this, but you can close the vertical gap above `.continut-langa-imagine` if you add the style declaration

```
vertical-align: top;
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #457c05;
    background-image: url('./img/img03.jpg');
}

.container {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.titlu-website {
    color: #1A1A1A;
    font-size: 64px;
}

.meniu-navigatie {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button-link {
    padding: 0 30px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Nova Mono', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #B5B5B5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.active {
    padding-left: -10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.titlu {
    color: #1A1A1A;
}

.continut-langa-imagine {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #808080;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 180%;
    width: 400px;
}

.imagine-centrala {
    border: 6px solid #EEE7DF;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="titlu-website">
            Black/White
        </div>
        <ul class="meniu-navigatie">
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link active">Home</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Photos</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Links</a></li>
            <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="continut">
        <div class="rand">
            <h3 class="titlu">Welcome to Black/White</h3>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="imagine-centrala">
            <div class="continut-langa-imagine">
                Sed lacus. Donec lectus. Nullam pretium nibh ut turpis. Nam bibendum. In nulla tortor, elementum ipsum. Proin imperdiet est. Phasellus dapibus semper urna. Pellentesque ornare, orci in felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus egestas at sem.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was right. Thanks a lot for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the block containing the image, text and header to a css-grid:
`.rand { display: grid; grid-template-columns: min-content auto; grid-column-gap: 10px; }`

This will give the image as much space as needed and the remaining space will be used by the text.

To let the header use the whole width I added:

`.titlu { grid-column: span 2; }`

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #457c05;
  background-image: url('./img/img03.jpg');
}

.container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.titlu-website {
  color: #1A1A1A;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.meniu-navigatie {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-link {
  padding: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Nova Mono', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #B5B5B5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.active {
  padding-left: -10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.rand {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.titlu {
  color: #1A1A1A;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.continut-langa-imagine {
  color: #808080;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 180%;
  width: 400px;
}

.imagine-centrala {
  border: 6px solid #EEE7DF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="titlu-website">
        Black/White
      </div>
      <ul class="meniu-navigatie">
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Photos</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Links</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="continut">
      <div class="rand">
        <h3 class="titlu">Welcome to Black/White</h3>
        <img src="./img/img02.jpg" class="imagine-centrala">
        <div class="continut-langa-imagine">
          Sed lacus. Donec lectus. Nullam pretium nibh ut turpis. Nam bibendum. In nulla tortor, elementum ipsum. Proin imperdiet est. Phasellus dapibus semper urna. Pellentesque ornare, orci in felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus
          egestas at sem.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Using float:

Just add `float: left;` to the image and preferably a margin right and bottom as in the snippet here:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #457c05;
  background-image: url('./img/img03.jpg');
}

.container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.titlu-website {
  color: #1A1A1A;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.meniu-navigatie {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-link {
  padding: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Nova Mono', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #B5B5B5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.active {
  padding-left: -10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.titlu {
  color: #1A1A1A;
}

.continut-langa-imagine {
  color: #808080;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 180%;
  width: 400px;
}

.imagine-centrala {
  border: 6px solid #EEE7DF;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="titlu-website">
        Black/White
      </div>
      <ul class="meniu-navigatie">
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link active">Home</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Photos</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Links</a></li>
        <li class="buton-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="continut">
      <div class="rand">
        <h3 class="titlu">Welcome to Black/White</h3>
        <img src="./img/img02.jpg" class="imagine-centrala">
        <div class="continut-langa-imagine">
          Sed lacus. Donec lectus. Nullam pretium nibh ut turpis. Nam bibendum. In nulla tortor, elementum ipsum. Proin imperdiet est. Phasellus dapibus semper urna. Pellentesque ornare, orci in felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus
          egestas at sem.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an approach using float, please? :)

Comment: added to the anwser as requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've accepted the other answer because of the simplicity and because I didn't have to change my layout, but I appreciate your time a lot and I will study your answer.